# arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type and it doesn accept Zip package

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, zip

I am trying to do mail merge using docx and excel in python and I am struggling with my code :

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import sys
from docxtpl import DocxTemplate

fname2=r"Agent Letter.docx"
df=pd.read_excel(r"Agents 2 Address Line.xlsx")
```

it reads all these files

```
zip_code=df["zip"].values
agent_state=df["agent_state"].values
pw=df["pw"].values
agent_address_1=df["agent_address_1"].values
primary_owner=df["primary_owner"].values
agent_city=df["agent_city"].values
wr_id=df["wr_id"].values
agent_name=df["agent_name"].values
agent_address_2=df["agent_address_2"].values


final=zip[zip_code,agent_state,pw,agent_address_1,primary_owner,agent_city,wr_id,agent_name,agent_address_2]
```

when running the above code I get this error:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-37982563d551> in <module>
----> 1 final=zip[zip_code,agent_state,pw,agent_address_1,primary_owner,agent_city,wr_id,agent_name,agent_address_2]
IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type
```

```
for a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i in final:


    doc=DocxTemplate(fname2)

    context={"zip_code":a,"agent_state":b,"pw":c,"agent_address_1":d,"primary_owner":e,
             "agent_city":f,"wr_id":g,"agent_name":h,"agent_address_2":i}
    
      doc.render(context)
      doc.save('{}.docx'.format(b))
    
print("All Files done")
```

Thank you
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need parentheses

```
final=zip(zip_code,agent_state,pw,agent_address_1,primary_owner,agent_city,wr_id,agent_name,agent_address_2)
```

instead of square brackets.